# CPI inflation index calculation

Tags: economics

I have a question about calculating the rate of inflation between two time periods using the CPI index, generally, if I am interested in comparing the rate of inflation between a current year 2022 and an earlier time period, 2019, is the CPI index calculation as follows:
CPI 2022 index minus CPI 2019 index, divided by CPI 2019 index
[CPI(2022)-CPI(2019)]/CPI(2019) if the years are not consecutive?